# Reg un/load access denied

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, regedit

While trying to unload an HKLM\SOFTWARE subkey I kept receiving the error *Access is denied.* I tried loading/unloading a test key, but I still received the error.

[image: cmd - Access is denied]

I haven't been able to find any solutions online and am unsure what could be throwing this error.

Comment: You can't use wildcards for the <KeyName>: "<KeyName>
 

Specifies the **full path** of the subkey to be unloaded."

Comment: "*test" is the key name. It doesn't matter which key I try, I can't load it unload any of them.

Comment: What was your complete `reg load ...` command?

Comment: reg load hklm\software\test testbackup.hiv